# Is there any possible for kernel to free the task_struct already but still maintain its pid structure?

Tags: c, security, linux-kernel

I am a newbie in Linux kernel and have the following question.

These days, I find the following code for a Linux kernel exploitation.

```
/*
 * Add @count to a struct pid by connecting @count times
 * to a socket on which the owner of that pid called listen().
 * This lets us increment the refcount of a pid even after the
 * task is already gone.
 */
void add_to_refcount(int count, int listensock) {
  for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    int refsock = SYSCHK(socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
    SYSCHK(connect(refsock, (struct sockaddr *)&unix_addr, sizeof(unix_addr)));
    SYSCHK(accept(listensock, NULL, NULL) == -1);
  }
}
```

It means that the increment of the `count` of a pid can happen even after the task is already gone. Why can this thing happen? Is that possible?
I'm speculating that it's because the reference count for task and pid structure are independent and each will trigger its free process respectively. That is, the free process of task will not affect the free of `struct pid` if the pid count is not zero.

Comment: I'm not sure, but possibly this is what happens for zombie processes?  Perhaps the `struct task_struct` is freed when the process calls `_exit()`, but the `struct pid` stays around until the parent calls `waitpid()`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Are you sure that the free can happen at the time you mentioned? That is, the `struct task_struct` is freed after calling `_exit` and the `struct pid` can be freed after `waitpid`? Does the gap truely exist and where can I find the details?

Comment: No, like I said I'm not sure, it's just a guess.  The place to find the details is, of course, the kernel source code.